# Preferred approach to check optionals in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

In working with optionals in Swift, there seems to be two approaches to check if an optional type is `nil` or not.

```
var item: String? = "apple"

// Approach A
if item != nil {
    "item is \(item!)"
} else {
    "no item"
}

// Approach B
if let x = item {
    "item is " + x
} else {
    "no item"
}
```

Does it matter which approach I use to check the optional?

Comment: Nope.  Why would it matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are equivalent, but it's better to use:

- `let x = item` (optional binding) when you actually need and use the unwrapped value
- `item != nil` when you just need to know if it's not `nil`, but you don't need its unwrapped value

Unwrapping via the optional binding has a cost, so if you don't need the value there's no reason to extract it and assign to a variable. On the other hand, if you need the value, it's better if you unwrap only once via the optional binding (and avoid using the forced unwrapping `!`)

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way:

With option A, the system has to unwrap the optional twice. Once to check to see if it isn't nil, and once to handle the `!`.

With option B, the system only has to unwrap the optional once, when it does the assignment.

In any particular situation, go with the code that reduces the number of times the compiler has to unwrap the optional.

Answer (score 0):

Option one evaluate if your option is not null and allows you to auto unwrap it using the exclamation point.

The second option bind the optional value to the specified variable if your optional is different of null.