# Manual unwrapping vs. if let with Optionals

Tags: swift, option-type

When dealing with an optional in Swift, there are two different ways to access the value behind the optional if it exists. You can do a manual check:

```
if someOptional != nil {
    doSomethingWithValue(someOptional!)
}
else {
    //handle nil...
}
```

or, you can use an `if let` block to unwrap the optional automatically:

```
if let unwrapped = someOptional {
    doSomethingWithValue(unwrapped)
}
else {
    //handle nil...
}
```

Is one of these options preferable to the other for any reason? Which, if either, is more idiomatic?

EDIT: In response to the close votes, I'm attempting to ask if there is a reason to use one over the other for any reason other than preference, whether it is for performance reasons, safety reasons, or something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26692837/1271826. Primarily opinion-based, too.

Comment: Yep, looks like those are duplicates. Voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one line of code in your "manual check": Before checking

> if someOptional != nil

you'd rather had to assign by something like:

```
someOptinal : <TypeOptional>? = anyFunctionThatProvidesAnOptional
```

And therefore this is my opinion: The second way (the so called "optional binding") combines that two lines in one line, so it is shorter and therefore better way.

Comment: Well, both of the code snippets assume that `someOptional` is a variable of some optional type that was assigned previously, though I don't see how the second one doesn't have the same issue...